# Creating a 'Zoom' like dynamic gallery view in CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css

I have an application where I want to create a full sized HTML page for displaying on a Kiosk.
Javascript will change the number of images depending on how many people are interacting with the kiosk (this side is all handled).

I could have one image, it could be two, three, four, anything up to 7x7 = 49.

I want to create a layout that looks very similar in how 'Zoom' creates the gallery view.
For instance:

- One image: would be 100% width and height of the page
- Two images: would do 50% width/height, showing eachother side by side with letterboxing top and bottom of the page
- Three images: two on the top line, one on the bottom - with the bottom one horizontally centred
- Four images: 2x2 grid
- Five images: three on the top line, two on the bottom line
- etc
- Nine images: 3x3 grid

You get the picture!

I've spent a good few hours today trying to solve this. I don't really have working code to show any more as I have tried lots of options. I have tried pure CSS, jquery manipulating tables, utilities that create masonry galleries, etc. None seem to achieve what I want.

Does anyone have any bright ideas on how to make this happen?

It's running on Chrome in a controlled environment so don't need to worry about cross browser compatibility and can generally get away with using most options for technologies to get this to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted the new people to come in at the bottom/left then grid would be the answer. But to get the bottom row centered we need to turn to flex.

As you will probably be using JS to insert or remove people you can calculate how many columns you need each time and reorganize the screen.

Here's a snippet showing the calculation. Change the number of divs in #container to see the effect. The aspect ratio for the person div is set in JS as variable personAspect. Currently set to 16:9 but can be altered as required.

```html
<head>
<style>
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#screen {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
  }
  
#container {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.person {
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ju8HY.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
</style>
<style id="person">
</style>
</head>

<div id="screen" >
  <div id="container">
    <div class="person"></div>
    <div class="person"></div>
    <div class="person"></div>
    <div class="person"></div>
    <div class="person"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
const personAspect = 16/9; /* SET TO WHAT YOU WANT IT TO BE FOR EACH PERSON DIV */
const maxCols = 7;
const screen = document.getElementById("screen");
const container = document.getElementById("container");

function reorganize() {
  const people = container.querySelectorAll('.person');
  const numPeople = people.length;
  const screenAspect = window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight;

  let cols = 1;
  for (cols; cols <= maxCols; cols++) {
    if (numPeople <= (cols * cols)) { break; }
  }
  
  let w = 0; //will be of the container in px
  let h = 0; //will be height of the container in px

  if (numPeople > (cols * (cols-1))) {// > OK for 5 and 6 not OK for 7
    h = window.innerHeight;
    w = h * personAspect;
  } else {
    w = window.innerWidth;
    h = w / personAspect;
  }
  
  container.style.width = w + 'px';
  document.getElementById('person').innerHTML = '.person {flex: 0 0 ' + (100/cols) + '%; height: ' + (h/cols) + 'px;}';
  if (numPeople <= (cols * (cols-1))) {h = h- h/cols;}// for when last row is empty
  container.style.marginTop = (- h)/2 + 'px';
}

reorganize();
window.onresize = reorganize;//not needed for final production but to make it easier to use the real window aspect ratio when developing
</script>
</body>
```